# How to pass vector<int>v[n] as perameter in function?

Tags: c++

I am constructing `k`-array tree using `vector<int>tree[n+1]` like `tree[parent].push_back(child)`. I want to pass this vector in function to perform  various task. So please help me how can i do it?
I just want to use `tree[NODE]` in sum function.

```
 vector<int>tree[NODE];
        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>u>>v;
            tree[u].push_back(v);
        }
       int k= sum(v,1);
```

where sum(1) is(No need to understand logic i just want way of using `tree` in sum)

```
int sum(int node)
{
    visited.push_back(node);
    if(tree[node].size()==0)
        return a[node];
 int ans=a[node];
    for(int i=0;i<tree[node].size();i++)
    {
        int next_node=tree[node][i];

       ans+=sum(next_node);

    }
    return ans;

}
```

Comment: The issue is not vector.  That is an array of `n` things and you pass an array of `n` things just like you would in any other case where you are passing arrays.

Comment: Do not describe your declarations, show them. See the concept of making a [mcve], which is helpful even if this is not a "code does not work" question. Try to show code which declares and contains pseudo code (e.g. comments) to show how you want to use the defined data structures.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried that way but it gives error in sum functions as `request for member 'size' in '(& tree)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<int, std::allocator<int> >(((std::vector<int>::size_type)node))', which is of non-class type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::value_type {aka int}'|`

Comment: `vector<int>tree[NODE];` is almost certainly not the right declaration. You *probably* want `vector<int> tree(NODE);`, which is *one* vector of `NODE` integers, not `NODE` vectors of zero integers

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to use tree[NODE] in sum function

Why don't pass it as a parameter? You need also somehow pass the size of the array.
There are two options:

```
void sum(std::vector<int> tree[], size_t size)
{

}

// at call site
sum(tree, Node);
```

and

```
template <size_t Count>
void sum(std::vector<int> (&tree)[Count])
{    
}

// at call site - will deduce array size automatically
sum(tree);
```